# celery apply_async returning missing argument error

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I have a celery function with definition -

```
@async_worker.task(ignore_result=True, queue="data_path")
def publish_msg_from_lock(self, mac: str, data: bytes, gateway_euid: str):
```

previously it wasn't a celery task it was being called like this -

```
n.publish_msg_from_lock(addr, unhexlify(payload), gateway_euid)
```

After making it a celery task I updated the call in this way -

```
n.publish_msg_from_lock.apply_async(args=(addr, unhexlify(payload), gateway_euid),)
```

I've also tried -

```
n.publish_msg_from_lock.apply_async(args=(addr, unhexlify(payload), gateway_euid), kwargs={})
```

and

```
n.publish_msg_from_lock.apply_async(kwargs={"mac": addr, "data": unhexlify(payload), "gateway_euid": gateway_euid})
```

But I'm getting error -

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 531, in apply_async
    check_arguments(*(args or ()), **(kwargs or {}))
TypeError: publish_msg_from_lock() missing 1 required positional argument: 'gateway_euid'
```

Can you please help to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your task fail because it is not bound.
To use the parameter self in the function signature you need to add bind=True to the celery decorator.

Example:

```
@async_worker.task(ignore_result=True, queue="data_path", bind=True)
def publish_msg_from_lock(self, mac: str, data: bytes, gateway_euid: str):
```

It allows to access some celery functionality like described here https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks

You could also remove the parameter self if you don't need it.

```
@async_worker.task(ignore_result=True, queue="data_path")
def publish_msg_from_lock(mac: str, data: bytes, gateway_euid: str):
```

Comment: I trie bind,

after that I'm getting following errors - 

n.publish_msg_from_lock.apply_async(args=(addr, unhexlify(payload), gateway_euid, ), kwargs={})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 378, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 0: invalid start byte